# Error running auditd inside centos docker container: "Unable to set initial audit startup state to 'enable', exiting"

Tags: docker, systemd, audit

I'm trying to create a docker container with `systemd` enabled and install `auditd` on it.

I'm using the standard `centos/systemd` image provided in [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/).
But when I'm trying to start audit, it fails.

Here is the list of commands that I have done to create and get into the docker container:

```
docker run -d --rm --privileged --name systemd -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro centos/systemd
docker exec -it systemd bash
```

Now, inside the docker container:

```
yum install audit
systemctl start auditd
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Job for auditd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status auditd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I run:

```
 systemctl status auditd.service
```

And I'm getting this info:

```
auditd[182]: Error sending status request (Operation not permitted)
auditd[182]: Error sending enable request (Operation not permitted)
auditd[182]: Unable to set initial audit startup state to 'enable', exiting
auditd[182]: The audit daemon is exiting.
auditd[181]: Cannot daemonize (Success)
auditd[181]: The audit daemon is exiting.
systemd[1]: auditd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start Security Auditing Service.
systemd[1]: Unit auditd.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: auditd.service failed.
```

Do you guys have any ideas on why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [discussion](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2018-July/msg00078.html):

> At the moment, auditd can be used inside a container only for aggregating
> logs from other systems. It cannot be used to get events relevant to the
> container or the host OS. If you want to aggregate only, then set
> local_events=no in auditd.conf.

> Container support is still under development.

Also see [this](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-auditd.conf/):

> local_events
> This yes/no keyword specifies whether or not to include local events. Normally you want local events so the default value is yes. Cases where you would set this to no is when you want to aggregate events only from the network. At the moment, this is useful if the audit daemon is running in a container. This option can only be set once at daemon start up. Reloading the config file has no effect.

So at least at `Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:53:32 -0400`, this feature not support, had to wait.

Comment: I didn't know about the `local_events`. That explain the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your info.  As of 2023 July, I found that [auditd image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxkit/auditd), but I still cannot run it.  Any update?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @atline! It applies also to systems running on a VPS which usually run in some kind of a container. At first I thought that running auditd on my host system shouldn't need disabling local_events, but then I realized that my host system is actually running on a VPS which probably runs in a container itself :)